# Android google map incomplite view

Tags: android, image, dictionary, google-maps-api-2, api-key

can somebody tell me why my map like this..

[image]

i've tried to change with new API KEY and keep like this 
for additional information, i use google map v2
thank you

Comment: It won't be easy to help you if you don't provide any piece of code. 
I had issues like this using a map fragment, if you're using this too, I suggest that you take a look at SupportMapFragment instead.

Comment: yes, i used fragmentActivity.. where i should check... which part ?

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at the documentation for SupportMapFragment : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment . It's really detailed, and explains you how to instantiate it and which methods you should call to get your map working. And here is a link with an example of implementation : http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-supportmapfragment-example/

Comment: After i try to update my google play service , map show nothing... do you think google play service lib coz all of this...?

Comment: I really don't think that Google play services are causing the map not to show. If they weren't installed on your device, it would print a button "Get Google Play Services". Did you try to use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment ?